# como cambiar puertos 80 y 3306 correctamente de xampp 3.2.2 e interactuar con workbench

Tags: xampp

Migré de una version antigua xampp al xampp 3.2.2 para php7, bueno ahora tengo errores despues de instalarlo. con los puertos como cambio los puertos 80 a 8080 y 3306 a 3307 correctamente y si es por ahi el camino? tambien hay un choque con workbenck mysql con los puertos.

Comment: Cuando das admin para que te mande a la pagina dice la pagina localhost ha rechazado la conexión

Comment: ¿migraste xampp o migraste un código en PHP?¿Qué errores?¿El camino a dónde?¿Que tipo de choque?

Answer (score 2):

en el panel de xampp clic en el botón config de apache y en httpd.conf busca la linea que dice Listen 80 y cámbiala por 8080. Lo mismo con MySql, en my.ini buscas port y cambias 3306 por 3307. 
Nota: el puerto 3306 lo cambias en dos lugares, en [client] y en [mysqld] dentro de my.ini. Luego en el botón de conf de apache selecciona PHP(php.ini) y busca las lineas

```
mysql.default_port=3306
mysqli.default_port=3306
```

y cámbialas por el puerto que definiste en my.ini en este caso 3307.

Comment: ahora me muestra.. Error
#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
 mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'pma'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
 La conexión para controluser, como está definida en su configuración, fracasó.
 mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: ya amigo me faltaba un archivo por editar disculpa. He editado mi respuesta para que veas lo que falta

Comment: Gracias pero sigo con el mismo error del 2 jun. 13:05

Comment: pero ese error te lo está dando cuando tratas de entrar a phpmyadmin o a la hora de guardar algo mediante tu app?

Comment: Ya hice estos cambios y ahora no puedo entrar a localhost